# Heap size vs "Running Services" memory allocation

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, heap-memory, allocation

I have a service that runs in its own process, separate from the activity, on Android 4.2.2 (CM10.1.3). It decodes a bitmap from resources (for a notification) through:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.icon);
```

I've noticed the memory used by the process under "Running services" is ~4.6mB in this situation and remains so for many hours. Even if I don't set the notification (icon is never used/referenced elsewhere), the memory remains at 4.6mB. This makes me believe that the memory of the bitmap is never released. If I erase the above line, the memory used shown in Running services is ~3.0mB.

I started looking into this and checked my heap size with DDMS. It shows as 2.3mB. First of all, **Why doesn't the "Running services" allocation match the JVM heap size?**

As I understand, before Android 2.3, Bitmaps were allocated in native memory and not Dalvik JVM memory. Therefore, before Android 2.3 you would expect to NOT see the bitmap in the JVM, but I should be seeing it in Android 4.2.2.

Secondly, **Why isn't the memory of the bitmap released/garbage collected (even if not using the object)?**

I have seen the memory come down to ~3mB from ~4.6mB but after many many hours (10+). Calling icon.recycle() and manually invoking the GC through DDMS does not bring it down immediately.